# Inserting an IEnumerable<T> collection with Dapper errors out with "class is not supported by Dapper."

Tags: c#, vb.net, insert, dapper

Yep, there are [questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957774/performing-inserts-and-updates-with-dapper) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379478/clarification-of-dapper-example-code) about how to insert records with dapper-dot-net. However, the answers, while informative, didn't seem to point me in the right direction. Here is the situation: moving data from SqlServer to MySql. Reading the records into an `IEnumerable<WTUser>` is easy, but I am just not getting something on the insert. First, the 'moving records code':

```
//  moving data
Dim session As New Session(DataProvider.MSSql, "server", _
                           "database")

Dim resources As List(Of WTUser) = session.QueryReader(Of WTUser)("select * from tbl_resource")


session = New Session(DataProvider.MySql, "server", "database", _
                      "user", "p@$$w0rd")

//    *edit* - corrected parameter notation with '@'
Dim strInsert = "INSERT INTO tbl_resource (ResourceName, ResourceRate, ResourceTypeID, ActiveYN) " & _
                "VALUES (@ResourceName, @ResourceRate, @ResourceType, @ActiveYN)"

Dim recordCount = session.WriteData(Of WTUser)(strInsert, resources)

//  session Methods
    Public Function QueryReader(Of TEntity As {Class, New})(ByVal Command As String) _
                                                            As IEnumerable(Of TEntity)
        Dim list As IEnumerable(Of TEntity)

        Dim cnn As IDbConnection = dataAgent.NewConnection
        list = cnn.Query(Of TEntity)(Command, Nothing, Nothing, True, 0, CommandType.Text).ToList()

        Return list
    End Function

    Public Function WriteData(Of TEntity As {Class, New})(ByVal Command As String, ByVal Entities As IEnumerable(Of TEntity)) _
                                                          As Integer
        Dim cnn As IDbConnection = dataAgent.NewConnection

        //    *edit* if I do this I get the correct properties, but no data inserted
        //Return cnn.Execute(Command, New TEntity(), Nothing, 15, CommandType.Text)

        //    original Return statement
        Return cnn.Execute(Command, Entities, Nothing, 15, CommandType.Text)
    End Function
```

cnn.Query and cnn.Execute call the dapper extension methods. Now, the WTUser class (note: the column name changed from 'WindowsName' in SqlServer to 'ResourceName' in MySql, thus the two properties pointing to the same field):

```
Public Class WTUser
    //    edited for brevity - assume the following all have public get/set methods
    Public ActiveYN As String
    Public ResourceID As Integer
    Public ResourceRate As Integer
    Public ResourceType As Integer
    Public WindowsName As String
    Public ResourceName As String

End Class
```

I am receiving an exception from dapper: "WTUser is not supported by Dapper." This method in DataMapper (dapper):

```
    private static Action<IDbCommand, object> CreateParamInfoGenerator(Type OwnerType)
    {
        string dmName = string.Format("ParamInfo{0}", Guid.NewGuid());
        Type[] objTypes = new[] { typeof(IDbCommand), typeof(object) };

        var dm = new DynamicMethod(dmName, null, objTypes, OwnerType, true); // << - here
        //    emit stuff

        //    dm is instanced, now ...
        foreach (var prop in OwnerType.GetProperties().OrderBy(p => p.Name))
```

At this point OwnerType =

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[CRMBackEnd.WTUser,
>   CRMBE, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

It seems like OwnerType should be `CRMBackEnd.WTUser` ... not `List<CRMBackEnd.WTUser>` ... ???  because what is happening is that the collection properties are being iterated: Count, Capacity, etc.  **What am I missing?**

**Update**

If I modified session.WriteData as:

```
Public Function WriteData(Of TEntity As {Class, New})(ByVal Command As String, _
                                                      ByVal Entities As IEnumerable(Of TEntity)) _
                                                      As Integer
    Dim cnn As IDbConnection = dataAgent.NewConnection
    Dim records As Integer

    For Each entity As TEntity In Entities
        records += cnn.Execute(Command, entity, Nothing, 15, CommandType.Text)
    Next

    Return records
End Function
```

records are inserted nicely ... but I didn't think this would be necessary given examples like:

```
connection.Execute(@"insert MyTable(colA, colB) values (@a, @b)",
    new[] { new { a=1, b=1 }, new { a=2, b=2 }, new { a=3, b=3 } }
  ).IsEqualTo(3); // 3 rows inserted: "1,1", "2,2" and "3,3"
```

... from [dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I just added a test for this:

```
class Student
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public void TestExecuteMultipleCommandStrongType()
{
    connection.Execute("create table #t(Name nvarchar(max), Age int)");
    int tally = connection.Execute(@"insert #t (Name,Age) values(@Name, @Age)", new List<Student> 
    {
        new Student{Age = 1, Name = "sam"},
        new Student{Age = 2, Name = "bob"}
    });
    int sum = connection.Query<int>("select sum(Age) from #t drop table #t").First();
    tally.IsEqualTo(2);
    sum.IsEqualTo(3);
}
```

It works as advertised. I made a few amendments to the way multi-exec works (so its a tad faster and supports object[]).

My guess is you were having issues cause you were missing a getter property on all you fields on `WTUser`. All params must have reader properties, we do not support pulling this from fields, it would require a complex parsing step to stay efficient.

---

An additional point that caused an issue is passing dapper a param with unsupported mapping.

For example, the following class is not supported as a param:

```
class Test
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public User User {get; set;}
}

cnn.Query("select * from Tests where Id = @Id", new Test{Id = 1}); // used to go boom
```

The issue is that dapper did **not** parse the SQL, it assumed all the props are settable as params but was unable to resolve the SQL type for `User`.

Latest rev resolves this

Comment: Edited WTUser: all of the `Public` *fields* are getter/setter ... I edited for brevity's sake: VB is grossly verbose. I will clarify the post.  ;)

Comment: @Sam is this solution generic? i.e. does it work on Oracle?

Comment: How do I get the ID's back for the entities that I insert?